# Custom Module ACl not working in Magento

Tags: magento-1.9

```
<config>
    <menu>
      <report>
            <title>Reports</title>
            <sort_order>80</sort_order>       
             <children>
               <customreport>
                 <title>Category base Reports</title>
                 <action>customreports/report_index/customreport</action>
                 <sort_order>10</sort_order>
               </customreport>
             </children>
      </report>
    </menu>
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <all>
                <title>Allow everything</title>
            </all>
            <admin>
                <children>
                    <report>
                        <children>
                            <customreports translate="title" module="customreports">
                                <title>Category base Reports</title>
                                <sort_order>60</sort_order>
                            </customreports>
                        </children>
                    </report>
                </children>
            </admin>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</config>
```

Comment: please provide the code used for ACL

Comment: <acl>
        <resources>
   <all>
                <title>Allow everything</title>
            </all>
            <admin>
                <children>
     <report>
      <children>
       <customreports translate="title" module="customreports">
        <title>Category base Reports</title>
        <sort_order>60</sort_order>
       </customreports>
      </children>
     </report>
                </children>
            </admin>
        </resources>
    </acl>

Comment: <menu>
   <report>
   <title>Reports</title>
   <sort_order>80</sort_order>    
    <children>
      <customreport>
     <title>Category base Reports</title>
     <action>customreports/report_index/customreport</action>
     <sort_order>10</sort_order>
      </customreport>
    </children>
   </report>
 </menu>

Comment: have you created admin controller at location customreport/adminhtml_..? can you share controller code?

Comment: can you see this thing `system->permission` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add complete menu in **ACL** too

```
<config>
    <menu>
      <report>
            <title>Reports</title>
            <sort_order>80</sort_order>       
             <children>
               <customreport>
                 <title>Category base Reports</title>
                 <action>customreports/report_index/customreport</action>
                 <sort_order>10</sort_order>
               </customreport>
             </children>
      </report>
    </menu>
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <all>
                <title>Allow everything</title>
            </all>
            <admin>
                <children>
                    <report>
                     <title>Reports</title>
                     <sort_order>80</sort_order>       
                      <children>
                       <customreport>
                        <title>Category base Reports</title>
                        <action>customreports/report_index/customreport</action>
                        <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                      </customreport>
                    </children>
                  </report>
                </children>
            </admin>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</config>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<config>
    <menu>
      <report>
            <title>Reports</title>
            <sort_order>80</sort_order>       
             <children>
               <customreport>
                 <title>Category base Reports</title>
                 <action>customreports/report_index/customreport</action>
                 <sort_order>10</sort_order>
               </customreport>
             </children>
      </report>
    </menu>
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <all>
                <title>Allow everything</title>
            </all>
            <admin>
                <children>
                    <report>
                     <title>Reports</title>
                     <sort_order>80</sort_order>       
                      <children>
                       <customreport>
                        <title>Category base Reports</title>
                        <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                      </customreport>
                    </children>
                  </report>
                </children>
            </admin>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</config>
```